# how do i make my program startup before logging in?

Tags: windows, naudio, c#

I need to create a program that runs before a user logged in. I want to create that program in C#. Can someone give me a hint where and how to start.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write a Windows Service. Choose Project type Visual C#->Windows->Windows Service and have a look at MSDN what you have to implement

[Introduction to Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a windows service. Once you understand the concept it's easy. Basically it's an application that runs in the background (no UI) and is started from Windows.